# Updating a ProgressDialog using an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need a AsyncTask to run my ProgressDialog while I'm fetching data from the network.
I understand the AsyncTask. But I have the network calls in more than a dozen places. How can  I reuse a single AsynchTask class for all these calls as my call to the network is from different Activity?

This made me rewrite the AsyncTask wherever in the Activities there is a network call.

Comment: You want more then one file download in a single async, or one async used in more then one activiy?

Comment: yes a single ashyncTask i want to reuse in all the network calls.
And this class need to handle a ProgressDialog for all the coming Network calls.
Thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full details of your code it does sound to me as though you might be using AsyncTask in a way it was never intended.

From the [docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

In my mind AsyncTask is suitable for relatively **simple** asynchronous tasks such as **single** file download/stream etc. Once there is a need for more complicated asynchronous tasks then perhaps utilising the full functionality of Threads is called for. It all comes down to design and correct choice of available tool for the task...

Comment: A single ashyncTask i want to reuse in all the network calls. From different Activities in my application i want to call this asyncTask and get the data.It will get URL as parameter and perform the HTTP GET and return the result back.
And this class need to handle a ProgressDialog for all the coming Network calls until the response from the url get.
Thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends how involved your network calls are.  If they are quick and you're not pulling a lot of data, then the AsyncTask will be fine.

Ultimately, what you need to do is clean up you code and make sure you're not repeating any logic.   Make sure you're putting all the repeated logic in a single method.

So that you're not rewriting the AsyncTask for each Activity, make a "parent" Activity class where you define you're AsyncTask (and any other repeated logic).  Then have the activities that need to run your AsyncTask extend this Activity.

If, however, your network calls are somewhat involved, you're probably going to want to look into another way of doing it.  You may want to define a Service and bind all of your Activities to that service.

Comment: i think u can help me can u code your logic i mean the Super class Activity u defined above

Comment: Hey plz think how a activity can extend the second Parent class so this way will never help